# Acestream on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, dependencies, repository

Has anyone been able to install AceStreams? I had it [installed on 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763364/how-to-watch-acestream-sopcast-ubuntu-16-04-lts), worked fine, but the same repository doesn't work and the attempt to install from them returns the error of unmet dependencies. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763364/how-to-watch-acestream-sopcast-ubuntu-16-04-lts). It seems that this guy find a way to install Acestream.

Comment: That's us, communicating. I managed it, and a big thanks to him!

Comment: @Mookey, :) did you just forget that ?