# How to watch Acestream / Sopcast Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, streaming, sopcast

Have you guys used [Acestreams](http://acestream.org/)?
The repository has not yet issued for 16.04 LTS, but besides, it might not be free anymore.

Is anyone watching Acestreams/Sopcast with any other software + where can I find such software?

Thank you!

Comment: I'll try, but in 16.04 the trusty repository doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried this? This still requires acestream-engine, but you can then play the streams in any external player (e.g. VLC, mpv). https://github.com/jonian/acestream-launcher

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's now one step installation:

```
sudo snap install acestreamplayer
```

and to run it:

```
acestreamplayer.engine --client-console
acestreamplayer
```

If running the above commands after the successful snap installation fails with a `command not found` error, you might need to add `/snap/bin` to your `$PATH` ***or*** run it using the following commands:

```
snap run acestreamplayer.engine --client-console
snap run acestreamplayer
```

Based on info @ https://www.cnx-software.com/2018/04/15/how-to-install-and-use-acestream-easily-in-ubuntu-mint-linux/

Comment: Works on 18.04 LTS.

Comment: After running the first command to install, I just opened *Ace Player HD* from the menu, which started it up in the background. After that I clicked on an `acestream://` link and it opened automatically in VLC.

Comment: Sadly this is only version 2 of ace stream player.

Answer (score 25):

It works for me. Install only `acestream-engine`.

1. Install `acestream-engine`

   ```
   echo 'deb http://repo.acestream.org/ubuntu/ trusty main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/acestream.list
   sudo wget -O - http://repo.acestream.org/keys/acestream.public.key | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install acestream-engine
   ```
2. Install Kodi (XBMC)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install kodi kodi-pvr-iptvsimple kodi-audioencoder-*
   ```
3. Install addon p2p-streams for Kodi (video)

   https://superrepo.org/get-started/
4. Start acestreamengine no root

   ```
   acestreamengine --client-console
   ```

   or

   ```
   acestreamengine --client-gtk
   ```
5. Start Kodi

   Video - addons - p2p-streams - Addon Website-parsere

It is the only way.

Comment: OK, that was my mistake. I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: So I got it to work, although KODI seems to be freezing on its own will. Acestream engine is running as you said, and I can play the Addon Website Parsers, i.e. programs listed there. Any way of adding a new programme? I cannot copy/paste the acestream code into the "play from acestream link" as CTRL+V doesn't work. I'm mostly interested in English premierleague football.

Comment: Oh, and a big thanks, finally got KODI to work :D

Comment: Hey, @Mookey, did you solve the freezing problem? I have that too and it's driving me nuts!

(Also, what about the copy-paste issue?)

Comment: CTRL+C / V never works, yes. I haven't been able to find the solution, but there are Add-Ons which have the program you search for, rather than the need to copy past stream links. As for the freezing, I upgraded to kernel 4.6 where it hasn't happened yet.  Also, I use a second monitor for it now.

Comment: setting acestreamengine - buffer VOD 20,  buffer live - 50, 
It does not freeze

Comment: It does not work anymore! Cannot install p2p-stream.

Comment: You need to update your answer, as it stands it is not functional.

Answer (score 15):

I got this option running in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: https://github.com/jonian/acestream-launcher

Instructions:

1.**Prerequisites**:
If you are unsure that you have all the dependencies, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python python-psutil python-pexpect python-notify2 acestream-engine vlc
```

2.**Clone the repository**:

```
git clone https://github.com/jonian/acestream-launcher.git
```

3.**Run install.sh script as root**:

```
sudo bash ./install.sh
```

Now, once you have the URL of the streaming, run:

```
acestream-launcher URL
```

For example:

```
acestream-launcher acestream://edca97797b5749855c9c0d512312312312323
```

Enjoy.

Comment: This is a nice lightweight solution!  Don't forget to add the repository as in the first step of https://askubuntu.com/a/765407/14747 !

Comment: I'm getting the following error on Ubuntu 14.04: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/acestream-launcher", line 161, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/acestream-launcher", line 151, in main
    AcestreamLauncher()
  File "/usr/bin/acestream-launcher", line 44, in __init__
    self.start_acestream()
  File "/usr/bin/acestream-launcher", line 70, in start_acestream
    if 'acestreamengine' in process.name():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: E: Unable to locate package acestream-engine `ubuntu v18`

Comment: There is no `./install.sh` inside this repo :(

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way: Snap (I used it without problems in Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and now in Mate 18.04 beta).

To install just enter the following into the terminal:

```
sudo snap install acestreamplayer
```

To run for the first time, it is recommended to use the terminal:

```
snap run acestreamplayer
```

(without `sudo`)

The first configuration takes some time, it seems to block, but when it is finished, the player and the server icon will appear. And also the two shortcuts (server and player) are created in the Sound&Video Menu

Cheers

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 (unlike the acestream-launcher ones above).

Answer (score 4):

Found that it has been packaged here:

https://snapcraft.io/acestreamplayer

Working fine for me.