# Acestream Failed to Start on ubuntu 16.04 LTS 1

Tags: 16.04, kodi

I followed this guide [How to watch Acestream / Sopcast Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763364/how-to-watch-acestream-sopcast-ubuntu-16-04-lts) to install acestream on my desktop. Installation was successful and tried to run it and got the following error

```
$ acestreamengine --client-console
2017-01-01 17:57:25,595|MainThread|acestream|error during startup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core.c", line 1146, in 
  File "core.c", line 48, in 
  File "core.c", line 26, in 
  File "/usr/share/acestream/lib/psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/psutil/__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/acestream/lib/psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/psutil/_pslinux.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/acestream/lib/psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_psutil_linux.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/acestream/lib/psutil-1.2.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_psutil_linux.py", line 3, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Looking for help to make it work for kodi.
Newbie Here, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can't tell what caused the problem in the first place, but you should reinstall `pkg_resources`:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pkg-resources`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I switched back to Linux Mint and its working great.